# how to use iterator in a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, iterator

im studying c++ primer, and in one exercise, i have to do a recursive function that prints the elements on a vector.

I did this:

```
void printVector(vector<int>::iterator it1, vector<int>::iterator it2) {
cout << *it1 << " ";
if (it1 != it2-1)
    printVector((it1 + 1), it2);
}
```

is there another form to declare it, without the

```
if(it1!= ***IT2-1***)
```

i feel like its a mediocre solution couse i cant find another way.

thanks!!

Comment: vector<>::iterator is random access iterator, so the other way to write 'if (it1 != it2-1)' is 'if (it1 < it2)'.

Answer (score 4):

Your function does not accept empty range, which it should, and it is a good idea to put exit condition into begin of a recursive function:

```
void printVector(vector<int>::iterator it1, vector<int>::iterator it2) 
{
     if( it1 == it2 ) return;
     cout << *it1++ << " ";
     printVector(it1, it2);
}
```

Comment: Ninja'd. Whether using iterators or indices or some other method, you must somehow select elements sequentially in the vector.

Comment: first i did (it1!=it2), but then the program crashes... i imagine that it is couse it1 first get out of range and the program recognises it before the evaluation of "if" right? the problen is that i cant add first to the iterator and then evaluate :O

Comment: @GaryAndresGutierrezFajardo problem is you dereference iterator before you check if it is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
void printVector(vector<int>::iterator begin, vector<int>::iterator end)
{
    if (begin != end) {
        cout << *begin << " ";
        printVector(++begin, end)(;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you probably want to go at it in another way. It is pretty silly to do recursion when a simple loop will do. Instead, recursion is a tool to use in a more divide an conquer style. I.e. divide into two parts, then apply the same function to the first part and then to the second part.

Usually you then have some kind of cutoff point as to when you can actually do whatever it is you want to do, say for instance that you have less than N number of elements to work with or similar. This example is pretty contrived, because it only brings overhead to do it recursively.

```
template<class Iter>
void printVector(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    const auto dist = std::distance(begin, end);
    if (0 == dist) {
        return;
    } else if (1 == dist) {
        std::cout << *begin;
    } else {
        // Find the middle
        auto pivot = begin + dist/2;

        // Apply to first part
        printVector(begin, pivot);

        // Print separator
        std::cout << " ";

        // Apply to second part
        printVector(pivot, end);
    }
}
```

Please forgive any typos and other issues. Oh, I made it a template as well so that it accepts any random access iterators. That was mostly because it felt annoying to type `vector<int>::iterator` twice. That should probably be `vector<int>::const_iterator` by the way.